# Is there a way in windows to know if a process is not responding?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way to know when a process is hung? is there a win32 call for this?

Comment: Define hung! Stuck in an infinite loop or just in the middle of a long operation.

Comment: There isn't a universal way for processes to work normally. E.g. you can't use windows messages to check if an SQL Server instance is working properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You send it a `WM_NULL` with `SendMessageTimeout()`. If that times out after something like a second or three, it's not responding (though it might eventually, of course).

Comment: Hi Jerry, is that in VB or C++ ..?

Comment: @ibiza: Windows in general -- `SendMessageTimeout` is part of Windows itself, so anything that gives access to the Windows API should work.

Answer (score 7):

Just for other people passing by: It might be easier to use [IsHungAppWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmmm..."This function is not intended for general use. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows."

Comment: Best solution, IsHungAppWindow() checks that process is in message waiting state, it does not send any WM_NULL.